# Sounds effects in iPhone game

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, openal

I'm making an opengl game for iPhone. And I'm about to start adding sound effects to the app.  I wonder what's the best framework for this purpose.

Is AV foundation my best option?  Any others I'm missing, like Open AL perhaps?

Comment: Per comment below, you may want to add the openal and core-audio tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

General strength/weakness summary of iPhone sound APIs from a game perspective:

- AVFoundation: plays long compressed files. No low-level access, high latency. Good for theme song or background music. Bad for short-lived effects.
- System sounds: plays short (think 0-5 sec) sounds. Must be PCM or IMA4 in .aif, .wav, or .caf.  Fire-and-forget (can't stop it once it starts). C-based API. Appropriate for short sound effects (taps, clicks, bangs, crashes)
- OpenAL: 3D spatialized audio.  API resembles OpenGL and is a natural accompaniment to it. Easy to mix multiple sources. Audio needs to be PCM (probably loaded by Core Audio's "Audio File Services").  Pretty significant low-level access.  Potentially very low latency.
- Audio Queue: stream playback from a source you provide (reading from file, from network, software synthesis, etc.).  C-based.  Can be fairly low-latency.  Not really ideal for a lot of game tasks: background music is better suited to AVFoundation, shorter sounds to system sounds, and mixing to OpenAL or Audio Units.  Can record from mic.
- Audio Units: lowest public level of Core Audio. Extremely low latency (< 30 ms). C, and hard-core C at that. Everything must be PCM.  Multi-channel mixer unit lets you mix sources. Can record.

Be sure you set up your audio session appropriately, meaning you declare a category that indicates how you interact with the rest of audio on the device (allow/disallow iPod playback in the background, honor/ignore ring/silent switch, etc.).  AV Foundation has the Obj-C version of this, and Core Audio has somewhat more powerful equivalents.

Comment: I tried using System sounds, but it slowed down my project a huge amount. I tried AVFoundation after that, which was slightly better, but still slows everything down. I'm trying to create a rapidly-repeating click sound (like a click wheel). Which should I use?

Answer (score 1):

[Kowalski](http://kowalski.sourceforge.net) is another game oriented sound engine that runs on the iPhone/iPad (and OSX and Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Finch](http://github.com/zoul/Finch), an OpenAL sound effect engine writter exactly with games in mind.